# Badge notification in the new top bar

Tags: support, badges, notifications, top-bar

I discovered today that I was awarded the `Steward` badge for edit reviews, but there was no notification of this. In the previous top bar, there were two types of alerts - red for inbox, gray for notifications (or whatever they were called). In the new top bar, I can only see the inbox. Did I miss something, or are badges no longer notified about in the new top bar?

Comment: The "achievements" thing (where you get rep changes) turns green when you have notifications.

Comment: @Mat Aha, I missed that. It didn't occur to me to look for badge notifications there (they were by the inbox previously). Make this an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Badge notifications, apparently being a common use case of the old Notifications tab, were split out into the Achievements dropdown. It should look like this if you have a new badge (but no rep change):

[image]
<sub>Unfortunately the FHRC is not part of the actual icon.</sub>

Comment: Yep, its tooltip when "empty" is also "Recent achievements: reputation, **badges**, and privileges earned". :)